# Coloring selected days in date picker ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

When the relevant date is selected from the calendar in the program, I want that selected day to be red and other non-appointment days to be green. It's a ASP.NET MVC web app with javascript and jquery on client side.

```
<script>
    var today = new Date();
    var today_formatted = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + ('0' + today.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var user_busy_days = ['2017-12-09', '2017-12-16', '2017-12-19'];

    $('#datetimepicker12').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        sideBySide: true,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {

            calender_date = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);

            var search_index = $.inArray(calender_date, user_busy_days);

            if (search_index > -1) {
                return { classes: 'non-highlighted-cal-dates', tooltip: 'User available on this day.' };
            } else {
                return { classes: 'highlighted-cal-dates', tooltip: 'User not available on this day.' };
            }
        }
    });

    $( document ).ready(function() {

    $(function () {
        var array = [];
        $.get('@Url.Action("Kontrol", "Randevu")').done(function (data) {
            if (data!="") {
                array.push(data);
                console.log(array);
                console.log(data);
            }
        })

        var dateToday = new Date();
        $("#TxtBasTar").datepicker({
            monthNames: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
            dayNamesMin: ["Pa", "Pt", "Sl", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Ct"],
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var day = date.getDay();
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('d.m.yy', date);
                console.log(string);
                if (day == 0)
                    return ['',"markholiday"];
                else
                    return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
            },
            minDate: dateToday,
        });
    //    $('#datetimepicker').on('dp.show', function (e) {
    //        highlight()
    //    })
    //    $('#datetimepicker').on('dp.update', function (e) {
    //        highlight()
    //    })
    //    $('#datetimepicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
    //        highlight()
    //    })

    //    function highlight() {
    //        var dateToHilight = ["04/19/2019", "04/20/2019", "04/30/2019"];
    //        var array = $("#datetimepicker").find(".day").toArray();
    //        for (var i = 0; i - 1) {
    //            array[i].style.color = "#090";
    //            array[i].style.fontWeight = "bold";
    //        }
    //    }
    //}
    });
    });
</script>
```

I have created a date picker function like this, how can I add or change the coloring operation?

Comment: You should probably remove the references to ASP.NET MVC from the question as they really aren't that relevant to the question. The question (and title) should focus on the jQuery datepicker plugin.

Comment: Why don't you add your custom css style to the classess .non-highlighted-cal-dates{color:green !important} or .highlighted-cal-dates{color:red !important}

Comment: Check here same case [highlighting specific days in jQuery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582127/highlighting-specific-days-in-jquery-datepicker)